# Unset a mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

When you `unset()` a mysql result, does it free the memory like `mysql_free_result()` does?

Comment: You could try this yourself: http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  `unset()` clears the pointer to the result on php's side, but does not do anything to the result it points to.  The result of a `mysql_query()` is simply a numerical identifier so that MySQL knows which result you're referring for functions like `mysql_fetch_array()` and its companions.  You need to use `mysql_free_result()` to tell MySQL that you're done with that result; you can also unset the php variable afterwards as well, but as it's just a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), the time it takes to unset may not be worth the few bytes you save from unsetting it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm well aware of what a result is. The question was just if PHP was smart enough to drop any related memory (PHP often makes such assumptions). I took SeanJA's advice and it in fact does not.

Comment: Didn't mean to insinuate that you didn't, just clarifying for anybody who comes across the question in the future.  After all, it is a Q&A site :)

Comment: if you try to unset a freed result php breaks,but maybe depends on php version.